# Redirect Active Directory Authentication histories in MS SQL server?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

Is there a way that I can redirect active directory authentication logs / histories to SQL DB?

I am trying to find a way to log all domain users authentication activities to a SQL database, Is this possible? I don't find useful reference for this online. Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

My domain controller is Windows 2008R2SP1.

Comment: You can dump (and query) events with `wevtutil` and import that to SQL (for example event-triggered); a direct redirection is not supported.